# how to make rectangle view in showcaseview for listview

Tags: android, listview, showcaseview

I am using  https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView library for Showcaseview
how to make rectangle view instead of circle ?
and how to using it for one of the listview item?
thanks

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the [`CustomShowcaseActivity`](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/CustomShowcaseActivity.java) in the sample app.  It creates a rectangular showcase.  It defines a `CustomShowcaseView` with a constructor that sets the `width` and `height` of the showcase rectangle from resource file [dimens.xml](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml):

```
width = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.custom_showcase_width);
height = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.custom_showcase_height);
```

The `CustomShowcaseActivity` is associated to the ShowcaseView in the `Builder`.  This is also where the showcase target is set.

The `CustomShowcaseView` implements `ShowcaseDrawer` so you use `setShowcaseDrawer()`.  It's not a drawer, but rather a "draw - er".

The following shows this and targets a `listview` as you wanted:

```
ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.listView, this);

sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
            .setTarget(target)
            .setShowcaseDrawer(new CustomShowcaseActivity.CustomShowcaseView(getResources()))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: [MaterialShowCaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) that is a improved version of original ShowCaseView library.
It has more featurs like `sequence` and `.withRectangleShape()` in it.
An example of rectangle showcase is:

```
    // single example
new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(mButtonShow)
    .setDismissText("GOT IT")
    .withRectangleShape() // this makes it rectangle
    .setContentText("This is some amazing feature you should know about")
    .setDelay(withDelay) // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
    .singleUse(SHOWCASE_ID) // provide a unique ID used to ensure it is only shown once
    .show();
```

for use it for one of items, use a `if` in `onBindViewHolder` with specific `position` and show it simply.